# Disable "Import sources within a group must be alphabetized." Typescript error

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I'm using create-react-app-typescript and I cant disable the "Import sources within a group must be alphabetized." error.

https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript

I've tried putting the following in my tsconfig.json:

```
"rules": {
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "import-sources-order": "any",
    "named-imports-order": "any"
},
```

Comment: The `rules` configuration belongs in `tslint.json`, not `tsconfig.json`.